# Divider is not showing in the custom Jetpack Compose TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom `TextField` which has no problem in the single `TextField` but when I create a `Row()` and put two custom `TextField` inside that, the divider is gone.

My custom text field: I created a `BasicTextField` and set a column `BorderColumnState()` to draw border when the text field is focus

```
@Composable
fun InputTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue = TextFieldValue(""),
    labelText: String,
    withBorderModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    dividerColor: Color,
    dividerThickness: Dp = 0.5.dp,
    spacer: Dp,
    textStyle: TextStyle,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
    isDropDown: Boolean = false,
    valueChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(textFieldValue) }
    //This is used if we want to use it in DropDown
    if (textFieldValue.text.isNotEmpty() && isDropDown)
        value = textFieldValue
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    val dividerState = remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            value = it
            valueChange.invoke(it.text)
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .onFocusChanged {
                dividerState.value = !it.isFocused
            },
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->

            val mainModifier = if (!dividerState.value) {
                withBorderModifier

            } else {
                modifier
            }

            BorderColumnState(
                mainModifier,
                labelText,
                textStyle,
                spacer,
                innerTextField,
                dividerState,
                dividerThickness,
                dividerColor
            )
        }, keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions, enabled = enabled
    )
}

@Composable
private fun BorderColumnState(
    modifier: Modifier,
    labelText: String,
    textStyle: TextStyle,
    spacer: Dp,
    innerTextField: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dividerState: MutableState<Boolean>,
    dividerThickness: Dp,
    dividerColor: Color
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.wrapContentHeight(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
    ) {
        Text(text = labelText, style = textStyle)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(spacer))
        innerTextField()
        if (dividerState.value) {
            Spacer(
                modifier = modifier
                    .size(dividerThickness)
                    .background(dividerColor)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage custom text field**: When I want to use two custom text field inside a Row, the divider is gone

```
@Composable
fun EditProfileScreen() {

    val disableButtonState = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
 
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp, top = 32.5.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            CountryCodeAndMobileNumber(
                countryCodeList = listOf("+98"),
                clientInfo,
                disableButtonState,
                viewModel
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))

            InputTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textFieldValue = TextFieldValue("sasasasas@gmail.com"),
                labelText = stringResource(R.string.email_address),
                withBorderModifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .border(
                        width = 1.dp,
                        shape = AppShapes.small,
                        color = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE
                    )
                    .padding(4.dp),
                textStyle = AppFont.PoppinsTypography.caption,
                dividerColor = AppColor.neutralColor.SILVER_CHALICE,
                spacer = 8.dp,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email)
            ) {}
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CountryCodeAndMobileNumber(
    countryCodeList: List<String>,
    clientInfo: Client,
) {
    var mobileClientInfo = clientInfo

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {

        CountryCodeDropDown(
            list = countryCodeList,
            label = stringResource(
                id = R.string.country
            ),
            dividerColor = AppColor.neutralColor.SILVER_CHALICE,
            enabled = false
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(4.dp))
        InputTextField(
            textFieldValue = TextFieldValue("111111"),
            labelText = stringResource(R.string.mobile_number),
            withBorderModifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    shape = AppShapes.small,
                    color = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE
                )
                .padding(4.dp),
            enabled = false,
            textStyle = AppFont.PoppinsTypography.caption,
            dividerColor = AppColor.neutralColor.SILVER_CHALICE,
            spacer = 8.dp,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone)
        ) {
           
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you create a minified example without ViewModel and other components? This code has a lot of dependant Composable and data.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I changed and minified the codes

Answer (score 0):

```
val mainModifier = if (!dividerState.value) {
            withBorderModifier

        } else {
            modifier
        }
```

You can not assign modifier as a variable. that's why it's not working.

Edit your code like this:

```
BorderColumnState(
            Modifier.then(if (!dividerState.value) withBorderModifier else modifier),
            labelText,
            textStyle,
            spacer,
            innerTextField,
            dividerState,
            dividerThickness,
            dividerColor
        )
```

Comment: I changed the codes but the problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code on my IDE. Why are you setting the size for the divider?

I changed the spacer to this and that's working fine.

```
Spacer(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(dividerThickness)
        .background(dividerColor)
)
```

Comment: I add your codes. the divider is showing but the mobile number textField is gone and country code text field width is match size and the view is damaged.                   https://ufile.io/wod29jvy